# Set time between two if loops in java

Tags: java, timer

Hi i want to set the time interval for few seconds between two if conditions. In my coding first "if" condition executes, control will stop 3 seconds after that only second "if" condition will execute.I dont want to use thread thread concept. I want some other option in java like "Timer" class etc.I tried many times but cant find solution . Please give solution for that

Thanks in advance

Here my code:

```
package com.example;

public class TimeBetween {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int a=5;
      int b=3;
      int c;
      if(a!=0&&b!=0) {
         c=a+b;
         System.out.println("Addition:"+c);
      }
      if(a!=0&&b!=0) {
         c=a-b;
         System.out.println("Subtraction:"+c);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1) `if` is not loop, it is like conditional block

2) You may use [sleep(milliseconds);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) after first `if() { ...}` block.

From oracle documentation:

> Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period. This is an efficient means of making processor time available to the other threads of an application or other applications that might be running on a computer system. The sleep method can also be used for pacing, as shown in the example that follows, and waiting for another thread with duties that are understood to have time requirements, as with the SimpleThreads example in a later section.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solutions are either `Thread.sleep` or you could simulate sleep with:

```
Object o = new Object();
synchronized(o) {
    o.wait(3000);
}
```

If you want to use timer you could do something like this:
But beware that the timer starts a thread in the background.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimeBetween {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int a = 5;
        final int b = 3;

        Timer t = new Timer(true);
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int c;
                if (a != 0 && b != 0) {
                    c = a + b;
                    System.out.println("Addition:" + c);
                }
            }

        }, 0);
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int c;
                if (a != 0 && b != 0) {
                    c = a - b;
                    System.out.println("Subtraction:" + c);
                }
            }

        }, 3000);
    }
}
```